# Javascript SOAP action in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, soap

Im tyring to run a basic javascript soap action on a content editor web part in sharepoint but it does not work. If I take the code out of sharepoint it runs fine in IE, why would this be?

```
<button onclick="doStuff()" type="submit">Send</button>

  <textarea name="REQUEST_DATA" cols=120 rows=17 >
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
   <createModifyRequest>
  <username>josephs</username>
  <lookupIds>
    <lookupIds>4225</lookupIds><!--firepass-->
  </lookupIds>
</createModifyRequest>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
  </textarea>



<script language="javascript"> 

  function doStuff() {


    var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");


    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://tpdev-itreq.transpower.co.nz:7777/usr/services/CreateModifyRequest", false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "createModifyRequest");

    var userpass = "josephs" + ":" + "pass";
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + (userpass));

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    xmlhttp.send(REQUEST_DATA.value);

}
```

Comment: Your code is for Internet Explorer only and you probably want it to work with all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Then use Firebug with Firefox to debug your code. You can see what your code will send to the server and what the server will reply.

Comment: exactly, you use ActiveXObject which is only supported by IE. other browsers need you to use new XMLHttpRequest()